# How can I support arbitrary querystring params? (explode modifier?)

Tags: apiblueprint

My API allows users to filter a database table using query string params (ie. `?age=30&location=Philadelphia`). These params are different for each database table. How can I express that in API Blueprint?

The [API Blueprint spec](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#uri-template-variable) says it supports the [explode modifier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-2.4.2). [This RFC 6570 validator](https://bigbluehat.github.io/vue-uri/) suggests the explode modifier could accomplish this via an object, ie.

```
/api{?filters*}
```

And passing

```
{ filters: { age: 30, location: 'Philadelphia' } }
```

(The validator linked above illustrates this a bit better)

Of course, I'm not sure how to express the above in API Blueprint. Is it possible?